# hide or change value a line ( or lines ) at git commit but not locally

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-commit, git-push

i'm working on an application with a specific credential ( login , password , serverIP ) ...

for example : 
File /test.java :

```
  String RegDomain = "188.XXX.XXX.XXX";
  String RegPassword = "XXXXXXX";
  String RegUser = "XXXXX";
```

my need is when i commit , and/or push my code i'd like to found that the test.java as following:

```
  String RegDomain = "YOurDomaine";
  String RegPassword = "YourPassword";
  String RegUser = "UserName";
```

without changing the value on local repository .

Comment: You can't handle that with git (at least not easily) but you should encode them. Also you should externalize these credentials and config in a property file. The way to encode will vary depending on which framework you use (if you use any)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+store+password+in+repository

Answer (score 3):

One general way around this problem is :

- have the code read these values from a config file or the environment
- commit a *template* version of the config file or the script that sets the environment - e.g : some separate `config.template` or `env.template` file which contains values such as "YourDomain" or "YourPassword" ...
- do not commit the file which contains the actual values - e.g : add the config file name (`config.json` or `env.sh` or ...) to your repo's `.gitignore`

With this setup, after the first `git clone` of your project, the developper would have to run an extra setup step to create the environment to run the program.